# Integral of Devil´s staircase in $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about the integral in $[0,1]$ of the devil´s staircase function. It seems to me that is going to be $1$ but  i got it more or less intuitive and i cant make up a mathematical argument to prove it. Is it $1$ ? And how do i prove it ? Thanks.

After some thought i got this , let F be the devils staircase,

$\int_{0}^{1}F(x)$ = $lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1} g_n(x)$

where $g_n= (3/2)^n\int_{0}^{x}f_n(t) dt$

where $f_n$ is the caratheristic function of a certain $F_n$ when we construct the cantor set has $C(I)=\bigcap{F_n}$

Comment: If $f$ is that function, how is $f(x)$ related to $f(1-x)$?  They have the same integral, and their sum is ...

Comment: I dont really understand the question.

Comment: Length of the graph is not $1$.

Comment: Ah damn, then what is it ?

Comment: The graph connects $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$, so its length is **at least** $\sqrt{2}$.  The length would be equal to $\sqrt{2}$ only for the straight line segment.

Comment: Although the function is not piecewise linear, it is the pointwise limit of piecewise functions. Try  integrating each piecewise linear function, and then swapping the integral and the limit using your choice of convergence theorem. Edit: Even better! The convergence is actually uniform.

Comment: Yes but my problem was calculating the integral of each piecewise function cause we get an integral inside an integral and i wasnt finding a good way to deal with it.

Comment: But what is the value of the integral is it 1?

Comment: Are you trying to compute the length of the graph or the area underneath it?

Comment: First i was trying to do the integral but i got stuck and then i tried the lenght of the graph and i also got stuck , so both i guess.

Comment: Ive tried some more calculus for the lenght of the graph and im getting some results, Does anyone know how much it is supossed to give?

Comment: The arc length is $2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ denote the Cantor function.

1. $F$ is monotone-increasing and satisfies $F(x) + F(1-x) = 1$. So,

   $$ \int_{0}^{1} F(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} [F(x) + F(1-x)] \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}. $$
2. For any continuous monotone-increasing function $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, we have

   $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \| (x_i, f(x_i)) - (x_{i-1}, f(x_{i-1})) \| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[ (x_i - x_{i-1}) + (f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})) \right] = 2 $$

   for any partition $\{0 = x_0 < \cdots < x_n = 1\}$ of $[0, 1]$. Taking supremum over all the partitions of $[0 1]$ shows that the length of the graph of $f$ is $\leq 2$.

   For the Cantor's function, this upper bound is actually achieved. Indeed, for each given $n \geq 1$, consider the partition $\{x_k\}_{k=0}^{3^n}$ given by $x_i = i/3^n$. Then

   \begin{align*}
   \text{[length of $F$]}
   &\geq \sum_{i=1}^{3^n} \| (x_i, f(x_i)) - (x_{i-1}, f(x_{i-1})) \| \\
   &= 2^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{2n}} + \frac{1}{3^{2n}}} + (3^n - 2^n)\frac{1}{3^n} \\
   &\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 2.
   \end{align*}

   Intuitively, this is because the graph of $F$ consists of 'infinitesimally small stairs', and any increasing stair from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$ has length $2$.

Comment: Thanks !!!! I didnt know about that first identity, is it easy to prove? Also i dont understand how u make that step in the integral.

Comment: @PedroSantos Under the standard iterative construction (such as your $g_n$'s), all the intermediate functions $g_n$ also satisfy $g_n(x) + g_n(1-x) = 1$. So the identity follows by taking limit as $n\to\infty$. :)

Comment: Alright thank you my friend!